# Div sliding from above the footer on click on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble in sliding div from bottom of the page.

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamselvan/hapttwf6/24/)

When i click on the blue box (arrow-hover) the div slides Up(box-main).

But to hide the div(box-main) again i have to click inside the box-main div.

Instead i want to hide the div when i again click on the blue box(arrow-hover). I tried a lot,but was unsuccessful.

And also i used position fixed for both the boxes so when i zoom in the page the box is fixed and it hides the rest of the page. If i give position absolute or relative The Div(box-main) is visible below the footer, which doesn't look nice. Is there any other way to do this.

here is my code

HTML:

```
 <div id="container">
<div id="box-main"></div>
<div id="arrow-hover"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #container
{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#box-main{
    position: fixed;
    left:150px;
    bottom: -150px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 100;
}
#arrow-hover{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 100;

}
footer
{
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    height:50px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:500;
}
```

Jquery:

```
 $('body').on('click','#arrow-hover',function(){
    $('#arrow-hover').animate({
        bottom: '200px'
    },250);
    $('#box-main').animate({
        bottom: '50px'
    },250);
});



$('body').on('click','#box-main',function(){
    $('#arrow-hover').animate({
        bottom: '50px'
    },250);
    $('#box-main').animate({
        bottom: '-150px'
    },250);
});
```

And also i want to put an upward arrow in (arrow-hover)div so when clicked the div moves up and then the arrow should be downwards, so when again clicked the div hides. Is there any way of doing this in Jquery or javascript or css3.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since i don't rely on variables, i just added a class to your main box: "visible"

this class gets toggled in both animations, so it is set, when you show it, and removed, when you hide it:

**update**: to include some arrows in the clickable div, we add an "arrow up" class to the #arrow-hover element in the html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="box-main"></div>
  <div id="arrow-hover" class"arrow-up"></div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

then we add the toggleClass function, to your arrow-hover click handler, to switch between arrow-up and arrow-down class

```
$('body').on('click','#arrow-hover',function(){
if($('#box-main').hasClass("visible"))
{
    $('#arrow-hover').animate({
        bottom: '50px'
    },250).toggleClass("arrow-up arrow-down");
    $('#box-main').animate({
        bottom: '-150px'
    },250).toggleClass("visible");
}else
{ 
    $('#arrow-hover').animate({
        bottom: '200px'
    },250).toggleClass("arrow-up arrow-down");
    $('#box-main').animate({
        bottom: '50px'
    },250).toggleClass("visible");
}
});
```

all you have to do now, is define the arrow-up and arrow-down classes in your css and set a background image.

for those purposes, i use the icon font "font awesome"
http://jsfiddle.net/hapttwf6/28/
--> this is how it looks like ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot , is there any way of giving transition of arrows in the clickable div, upward when the slide moves up and downward when moves down....

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain a boolean variable and check its value and show or hide div accordingly.

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hapttwf6/25/)

```
var clicked = false;

$('body').on('click','#arrow-hover',function(){
    if(!clicked){
        $('#arrow-hover').animate({
            bottom: '200px'
        },250);
        $('#box-main').animate({
            bottom: '50px'
        },250);
        clicked = true;
    }
    else{
        $('#arrow-hover').animate({
            bottom: '50px'
        },250);
        $('#box-main').animate({
            bottom: '-150px'
        },250);
        clicked = false;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot..is there any way of giving transition of arrows in the clickable div, upward when the slide moves up and downward when moves down....

Answer (score 1):

see my updated fiddle :

```js
$('body').on('click','#arrow-hover',function(){
    $('#arrow-hover').animate({
        bottom: '200px'
    },250);
      $('#box-main').animate({
        bottom: '50px'
    },250);
    if($('#arrow-hover').css('bottom')!='50px'){
    $('#arrow-hover').animate({
        bottom: '50px'
    },250);
        $('#box-main').animate({
        bottom: '-150px'
    },250);
    }
});
```

```css
#container
{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#box-main{
    position: fixed;
    left:150px;
    bottom: -150px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 100;
}
#arrow-hover{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 100;

}
footer
{
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    height:50px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="box-main"></div>
<div id="arrow-hover"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hapttwf6/27/